# Search box filtering does not return the searched result- React+ react-table+ filter

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-table

I am using react-table as data-grid. I am implementing table based search filtering. The filtering does not seem like working , as a result its returning empty results. I do not where I am going wrong.

Can someone help?

Help would be appreciated

### Data format

```
let data =[  {id: 1, val1: "45GFSDSD", val2: "AKFHFDH83E3HHYE"},
             {id: 2, val1: "46FDGDGDGDG", val2: "AKFHFDH83E3HFGD"},
             {id: 3, val1: "56FDGGFGF", val2: "AERTFDH83E3HHYD"}
          ]
```

### Component code

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactTable from 'react-table';
class MyTable extends React.Component {

  constructor () {
      super();
      this.state = {
         data: data, // data from API, structure has been shown above
         search: ''
      }  
  }   

 render () {    
      let data = this.state.data
      if (this.state.search) 
      {
        data = data.filter((value) => {           
           return value.val1.includes(search)||value.val2.includes(search)|| String(value.id).includes(search)
         })
      }

      return (
       <div>
         Search: 
          <input value={this.state.search} onChange={e => this.setState({search: e.target.value})} />
          <ReactTable data={data} columns={columns} />//column object 
       </div>            
      )
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a codesandbox? It'll be easier to debug.

Comment: I've updated the example below, with `ReactTable`.

Comment: you can also remove the constructor and use your state like `state = {}`, which is way better than using the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have two arrays, one for data from the api and one for filtered data. Your state will be like.

```
//on first load both arrays will have the same data
state = {
  data: [
    { id: 1, val1: "45GFSDSD", val2: "AKFHFDH83E3HHYE" },
    { id: 2, val1: "46FDGDGDGDG", val2: "AKFHFDH83E3HFGD" },
    { id: 3, val1: "56FDGGFGF", val2: "AERTFDH83E3HHYD" }
  ],
  filteredData: [
    { id: 1, val1: "45GFSDSD", val2: "AKFHFDH83E3HHYE" },
    { id: 2, val1: "46FDGDGDGDG", val2: "AKFHFDH83E3HFGD" },
    { id: 3, val1: "56FDGGFGF", val2: "AERTFDH83E3HHYD" }
  ]
};
```

Then you'll need a function for filter data, when the text changes in the input

```
handleSearch = event => {
const search = event.target.value.toLowerCase();

this.setState({
  filteredData: this.state.data.filter(
    item =>
      (item.val1 && item.val1.toLowerCase().includes(search)) ||
      (item.val2 && item.val2.toLowerCase().includes(search))
   )
 });
};
```

Your input

```
<input
  type="text"
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleSearch}/>
```

Table gets data from filteredData array

```
<ReactTable data={this.state.filteredData} columns={columns} />
```

[working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zldk1q)

Comment: Thank you so much!