# How to get the initial data of the state in react

Tags: reactjs, searchbar

I am trying to implement a searchbox that will filter items that are coming from a rest endpoint and i can't get my head around how to keep the first state of the list because i need it to return it if the searchbox is empty... i try many examples with this.props.someItem but i always get error in the console TypeException i read about parent child components with no luck. Ive tried to make a child component do the query and fetch the data but then i didn't manage to get it into the parent class i tried "this.state = { foo[] : foo2 }"; not working i tried assign it directly foo = this.props.foo2; again with no luck i got TypeError. Sorry it can be easy question but i am very new to js and react. Thank you for any help in advance.

```
  class About extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            items: [],
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            items: nextProps.model
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('something/')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then((result) => {
                    this.setState({
                        items: result
                    });
                }
            )
    }
```

i have a function handleChange(e) => { }; how to get the initial state of the "items" array ? filteredList = this.props.items - ive tried this it gives me error TypeError: undefined ans also if i change the state it is ok but the original data is lost and i want to ask is it a good practice to fetch the data everytime if the query include the whole data for this view for example.

Comment: You need two arrays, one for filtered data and one for data from the api.

Comment: yes ive tried this approach but the api assign the data directly into this.state = {} and if i assign and the second array with the state condition it is changed in both afc and ive tried to use this.props but it dosen't work

Comment: do you have default data or you wait for the data to come from the api?

Comment: i don't have the data locally it is fetched into items array by componentDidMount()

Comment: handleChange = (e) => {

        let currentList = [];
        let newList = [];

        if (e.target.value !== "") {
           currentList = this.state.items;

           newList = currentList.filter(item => {
               const lc = item.model.toLowerCase();

               const filter = e.target.value.toLowerCase();

               return lc.includes(filter);
           });
       } else {

           newList = this.props.items;
       }

       this.setState({
           items: newList
       });

    } ive tried this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class About extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        items: [],
        filteredItems: []
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);

}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('something/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((result) => {
            this.setState({
                items: result
                //Note: You can set filteredItems here to result as well  
                //if you want it to start out unfiltered
            });
        }
        )
}
handleChange(evt) {
    const baseItems = this.state.items;
    //Your filtering logic here
    this.setState({ filteredItems: yourFilteredArray });
}
```

Comment: see my note in componentDidMount

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two arrays, one for original data and one for filtered data.

Your initial state will look like.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  this.state = {
    items: [],
    filteredList: [],
    isLoading: true, // show a spinner while fetching data from api
  };
  //....
}
```

Both of your arrays will have the same data, set the data from the api to both arrays.

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetch("something/")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
      this.setState({
        items: result,
        filteredList: result,
        isLoading: false,
      });
    });
}
```

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d66rad)

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55815153/search-box-filtering-does-not-return-the-searched-result-react-react-table-fi/55815701#55815701)

Comment: Both answers are working thank you both for the help i really loosed too much time with this before i asked the question i wish i have the option to accept both answers.